# what's the purpose of the refresh tokens in API of a mobile app

Tags: mongodb, passport.js, bearer-token

developing a mobile app using angularjs, node.js, mongodb, passportjs, express... Im implementing the bearer strategy with the bearer tokens. 
I would like to know, when a user is using the app(immediately after the user is logged the access token is created),but I would like to understand when the API must to refresh it or when the access token must to expire.

Answer (score 1):

Refresh token is used when access token expires. It's up to you when you expire the access token, but usually the lifetime of an access token is one hour. When the access token expires, the refresh token can be used to obtain a new access token. For more information, please refer to the [OAuth 2.0 RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749).

[Refresh token](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.5):

> Refresh tokens are credentials used to obtain access tokens. Refresh tokens are issued to the client by the authorization server and are used to obtain a new access token when the current access token becomes invalid or expires, or to obtain additional access tokens with identical or narrower scope (access tokens may have a shorter lifetime and fewer permissions than authorized by the resource owner).

[Expiration](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.2.2):

> expires_in
>
> RECOMMENDED.  The lifetime in seconds of the access token. For example, the value "3600" denotes that the access token will expire in one hour from the time the response was generated.